# Update / SET to MySQL with PHP/AJAX within a loop

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, input, datepicker

I need a small hint. Let's say there's a code like:

```
<?php
    $test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id='1'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['platform_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['scan_frequency'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td><input id='freq' type='text' /></td>";
      echo "<td><input id='date1' class='datepicker' type='text' /></td>";
      echo "<td><input id='date2' class='datepicker' type='text' /></td>";
      echo "<td><button id='save'>Save</button></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
?>
```

The logic is that when I run a page, I get platform name and scan frequency fetched from table test as supposed to. Then I need to fill out three inputs (new frequency and dates, which are in format yy-mm-dd) and send it back (update/set) using 'save' button to table test. How can I do it with AJAX/PHP?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Why are you using while when you (likely) have just one record?

Comment: This isn't that simple. You need to learn AJAX.

Comment: Well, that's basically is a small fragment of the code, I've got few placed like that, which are fetching the date from the database, and I need to send them back. I know basics of AJAX, I'll handle, just need a small hint how to iterate over these td's when trying to update/set new data into database.

Comment: @Pawel Then please post that code so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small hint. ;-)

You link the button attribute onclick to a javascript function (e.g. fetch_new_data). Then you define the function fetch_new_data, which sends an ajax request to the server. The server processes the ajax request, selects the new data, packages it as xml or json and sends it back to the client. On return of the data, you lookup the position of the table, where you want to insert the new data and extend the table with a few new rows.

You can look for [jquery](http://jquery.com), which simplifies several of these tasks on the client side. At the server side, for PHP and JSON, see [PHP - JavaScript Object Notation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) and any tutorial or example covering PHP+JSON and/or PHP+AJAX.

Comment: Ok, that's what I needed :-) I'll google some to understand it from the code point of perspective.